# Window7 C# Debug & Release Program, Difference Value(Processing Bitmap)

Tags: c#, debugging, bitmap, release, lockbits

I'm running a lot of tests on the two programs
(Window7 C# Debug & Release Program).

tag : Window7, C#, Bitmap, Lockbits, byte

The contents are as follows.

Bitmap spec(Image Size : 3072X3072)
[image]

```
Bitmap originImage;
int cnt = 0;
BitmapData bmOrigin = originImage.LockBits(
                      new Rectangle(0, 0, originImage.Width, 
                                   originImage.Height),
                      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                      originImage.PixelFormat);
byte* ptrOrigin = (byte*)bmOrigin.Scan0.ToPointer();
if (ptrDefect[y * bmDefect.Stride + x] == 255)
{
   cnt++;
}
```

Using the two programs, the contents are repeated 1000 times, and about 30 different results are obtained.

I have a suspicious place.
(Bitmap, Byte, 255Value, Scan, Lockbits)

Is there any place else I suspect other than what I said?

Thank you for reading this article. Please give us various opinions.

Comment: Can you clarify what's "different"?

Comment: The result of the "cnt" variable is different.